# how to create an array that excludes items from another array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have two arrays with different attributes for the objects contained in each.

```
participants

guests
```

The only field in common is `provider_user_id`

I want to do something like this

```
all_people = participants.map {|p| p.provider_user_id <> guests.provider_user_id }
```

This is probably not correct.

How can eliminate those participants who are also in the guests array?

Comment: Does `all_people` equate to guests who are not participants? Or are you wanting the combination of guests and participants but you want to avoid including the same person twice?

Comment: I want to avoid including the same person twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works, but I'd be interested if there's anything more concise.

```
guest_provider_ids = guest.map(&:provider_id)
non_guest_participants = participants.reject do |participant|
  guest_provider_ids.include?(participant.provider_user_id)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Could work...

```
guests.each { |g| participants << g }
guests.uniq! { |g| g.provider_user_id }
```

This (should) combine the two arrays first, then removes any duplicates based on the key.

Comment: That said, I didn't test it out of pure tiredness. It's probably not a good time for me to being handing out advice on StackOverflow. ;)

Comment: Ah - it was added in [1.9.2](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/tags/v1_9_2_0/NEWS). Warning: if you try using it on an older version, it'll just silently ignore the block.

Answer (score 1):

Good answers but don't forget about |. For 1.9

```
p (guests | participants).uniq!{|g| g.provider_user_id}
```

For 1.8

```
p (guests | participants).reject{|p| guests.map{|g| g.provider_user_id}.include?(p.provider_user_id)}
```

Comment: Don't forget about the `|` character? I guess we'd better not forget the `{` and the `}` either, right?